# Python3.8 pySerial sending int64 as signed bytes

Tags: byte, python-3.8, pyserial, int64, int32

I'm trying to convert a class 'numpy.int64'named "int_array" into bytes.
In the past I used this structure

```
(-1024).to_bytes(8, byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

and worked fine.
Now, saving all the integers into a matrix, it doesn't allow me to do this:

```
int_array[1][i].to_bytes(8, byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

If there is a function for integer32 it would also work.

Does anybody know an equivalent command?
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I dont understand then. I have the following err: 
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparently, in Python 3.8 I'm not allowed to do that.

The [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method is available since Python 3.2:

> New in version 3.2.

Alternatively you can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack(">q", -1024)
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfc\x00'
```

Comment: Struct seems to be working so far. Thanks